# displaying images from a function that returns an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, prototype

I have a function that randomizes an array of images and returns an array with the random images after they are displayed.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var images = new Array('0.jpg', '1.jpg' , '2.jpg'), result=[] ;
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    var that = this.slice();
    var length=images.length;
    var rand;
    for(i=0; i<=4;i++)
    {
        rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));
        result.push(images[rand]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`//document.write(images.random());` when I do this I get the array with the images but I want to display them using something like `document.write('<img src="images/'+images.random()+'" width = \"\" height = \"\"/>');`\but thats not working..any ideas

Comment: `images.random()` is returning an array. To display the images, you'll have to loop over the array.

Comment: Please don't put that `random` function on the Array prototype. It doesn't even use the array it is called on. Instead, use a static, generic function which you pass the array and the number of elements you want from it.

Comment: `rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));result.push(images[rand]);` appears to be able to make an array with duplicates, or rather not much different than just pulling a random at anytime. If you just want a random picture, I don't see the reason to rebuild the array. Just have `random` do `return images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];`. As well, I don't see a need to use `write` nor prototypes.

Comment: so for(i=0; i<=4;i++)
  {
 document.write('<img src="images/'+images.random()+'" width = \"75\" height = \"75\"/>');
 
 }

Comment: I want to display 4 random images of an array of 9 images and create an array with the random images that are being displayed

Comment: With or without duplicates? True random could possibly make an array like this: 2,2,9,9. Where the 2nd and 9th picture have randomly duplicated themselves. Avoiding that needs extra code. Otherwise, Mehran's answer is nice and elegant. If you need to store the array outside of just displaying it. You would need to `var ranImgs = images.random();` first, then `ranImgs.forEach(...`.

Comment: duplicates are fine.. i just want to display 4 images only..i added some code to Mehran's answer

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for ya

Comment: i havent been able to display the 4 images.. i added the following to Mehran's code images.random().forEach(function(imgname){

for(i=0; i<=4;i++)
{
    //document.body.appendChild(createImage(imgname));
 document.write('<img src="images/'+imgname+'" width = \"75\" height = \"75\"/>');
 }
 
});

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem** in whenever you do `document.write` it wipes all the DOM out. the better solution is to create your images using `document.createElement` and then append them to the body or to any other container you want.

first to make your code clear create a function like this:

```
function createImage(imgname){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/" + imgname;
    return img;
}
```

then do this:

```
images.random().forEach(function(imgname){
    document.body.appendChild(createImage(imgname));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some of the help provided by some of you and here is what i got. so this code takes an array of images, randomizes them, displays them

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images=new Array('g.jpg','f.jpg','f.jpg')
var re=[];
var length=images.length;
var entered=document.getElementById('images');
for(var f=0; f<4; f++){
var ran=Math.floor(Math.random()*(length));
var imge=document.createElement("img";
image.src="images/" + images[ran];
entered.appendchild(image);
</script)
```